# Binary String to Integer

Tags: c#, string, binary, integer

I have a binary string, entered by the user, which I need to convert to an integer.

At first, I naively used this simple line:

```
Convert.ToInt32("11011",2);
```

Unfortunately, this throws an exception if the user enters the integer directly.

```
Convert.ToInt32("123",2); // throws Exception
```

How can I make sure that the string entered by the user actually is a binary string?

- `try..catch`
- `Int32.TryParse`

Thanks

Comment: How does the user enter the string? If it's a form, couldn't you limit it to accept only '0' and '1'?

Comment: Why is `try` - `catch` "ugly"?

Comment: You are probably right, it is not that ugly. I actually went with it now because Hex value are suddenly possible aswell. So some simple try - catches are just the simplest and easiest solution. Thanks everybody.

Answer (score 35, accepted):

You could use a `Regex` to check that it is "^[01]+$" (or better, "^[01]{1,32}$"), and *then* use `Convert`?

of course, exceptions are *unlikely* to be a huge problem anyway! Inelegant? maybe. But they work.

Example (formatted for vertical space):

```
static readonly Regex binary = new Regex("^[01]{1,32}$", RegexOptions.Compiled);
static void Main() {
    Test("");
    Test("01101");
    Test("123");
    Test("0110101101010110101010101010001010100011010100101010");
}
static void Test(string s) {
    if (binary.IsMatch(s)) {
        Console.WriteLine(Convert.ToInt32(s, 2));
    } else {
        Console.WriteLine("invalid: " + s);
    }
}
```

Comment: This doesn't correctly handle conversion of Convert.ToString((long)Int32.MaxValue + 1, 2).  This should be rejected but is incorrectly converted to Int32.MinValue.

Comment: Why should that be rejected? It is a valid 32-bit binary value. If you choose to interpret it as int32 then sure: anything with the msb set is going to be negative... and?

Comment: Thanks great solution. I actually went with it. But the requirements changed some what so I decided try - catch is the simplest and cleanest solution

Comment: I don't have much Regex experience, does this check that there are 1-32 characters and these have to be either 0 or 1?

What's the best way to do a similar check for valid octal strings?

I wish that .NET would have a int.TryParse where you check for Binary and Octal instead of just Decimal and Hex

Comment: @R1PFake yes, `^...$` tests the start/end of the string (so: nothing else); `[01]` means "0 or 1", and `{1,32}` means "between 1 and 32 times, inclusive"

Answer (score 4):

Thanks for the great and incredibly fast answer!

Unfortunately, my requirements changed. Now the user can pretty much enter any format. Binary, Decimal, Hex. So I decided try - catch just provides the simplest and cleanest solution.

So just for good measure I am posting the code I am using now. I think it is pretty clear and even somewhat elegant, or so I think^^.

```
switch (format)
{
    case VariableFormat.Binary:
        try
        {
            result = Convert.ToInt64(value, 2)
        }
        catch
        {
            // error handling
        }
        break;
    case VariableFormat.Decimal:
        try
        {
            result = Convert.ToInt64(value, 10)
        }
        catch
        {
            // error handling
        }
        break;
    case VariableFormat.Hexadecimal:
        try
        {
            result = Convert.ToInt64(value, 16)
        }
        catch
        {
            // error handling
        }
        break;
}
```

So thanks for encouraging me to use try - catch, I think it really improved the readibility of my code.

Thanks

Comment: What, you don't like octal? Seriously though, what if someone enters '11' and meant it in base 10? Standard solution would be to use a prefix ('0b', '', '0x'), but that may not fit your requirements.

Comment: Yeah no octal^^. The user actually has to choose in combobox which format she wants to use. I thought about your solution too, but it seemed easier with a combobox. Thanks so great input.