# Convert binary string into integer

Tags: c#, .net, string, binary

I would like to convert a binary number writen in a String into its integer value.

For example:

```
string input = "0101";
int output = convert(input);
```

`output` should be equal to `5`

Comment: You should try googling "C# convert X to Y" before asking.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Binary String to Integer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1271562/binary-string-to-integer)

Comment: @TimLloyd the other question is newer? If anything that question is a dupe of this :)

Comment: @mhvelplund The question I linked to was asked on "Aug 13 '09".

Answer (score 125, accepted):

[Convert.ToInt32(String, Int32)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/1k20k614.aspx) lets you specify the base:

```
int output = Convert.ToInt32(input, 2);
```