# String of binary to integer

Tags: c#, function, methods

I have a string which contains of 0 and 1. I wanna know if there is any method in c# to convert this in Uint32 . I know how to do that without any method but just I wanna know if there is any method does that automatically?

Comment: `Convert.ToUInt32(...)`

Comment: This call would turn e.g. `1000000` to `1000000` instead of `128`. You'll have to use overloaded method which allows you to specify number base, so the call would be `Convert.ToInt32("10000000", 2)` (note that `Convert.ToUInt32` doesn't provide overload to specify number's base).

Comment: possible duplicate of [Convert binary string into integer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9149728/convert-binary-string-into-integer)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [`Convert.ToInt32 Method (String, Int32)`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/1k20k614.aspx) overload.

> Converts the string representation of a number **in a specified base** to
>   an equivalent 32-bit signed integer.

Like;

```
uint i = Convert.ToUInt32("010101", 2); //21
```

Here a [**DEMO**](http://ideone.com/9aBTla).

(010101)<sub>2</sub> = 2<sup>0</sup> * 1 + 2<sup>1</sup> * 0 + 2<sup>2</sup> * 1 + 2<sup>3</sup> * 0 + 2<sup>4</sup> * 1 + 2<sup>5</sup> * 0 = 21

Answer (score 7):

Try using the `Convert.ToUInt32` method.  There is an overload which allows you to specify the number base you are converting from

```
uint x = Convert.ToUInt32("01010", 2);
```

Here is the MSDN page for that member

- [Convert::ToUInt32](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/swz6z5ks.aspx)

Answer (score 4):

```
string s = "0101";
uint i = Convert.ToUInt32(s, 2); //<--5
```