# convert binary string to integer array in c#

Tags: c#

I want to convert binary value into integer array in c#.

For example consider binary value : 111 , it's integer equivalent is 7 (right most digit equals to integer 1, middle binary digit is equivalent to integer 2 and left most digit is 4, so 1+2+4 = 7).

how do I get each integer digit (i.e. 1, 2 ,4) in form of an array (or list) using c# ?

Comment: Can you rephrase your question.. ? Do you simply want the binary places? Or do you want the value 7 from the binary representation .. ? Provide some pseudo-code or something so we can see what you're after.

Comment: Why would you not just want the integer, and extract bits from that as required?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Convert binary string into integer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9149728/convert-binary-string-into-integer)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
string bin = "1011";

var str = String.Join(",", bin.Reverse().Select((c, i) => (c - '0') * (1 << i)));
```

str will be `1,2,0,8`. if you want the result as a list

```
var list = bin.Reverse().Select((c, i) => (c - '0') * (1 << i)).ToList();
```

Comment: @LB If you still want long, use `1L << i`. Or maybe `ulong`, use `1ul`. This will give strange results if string length exceeds 31, or 63, or 64 (`1ul`), so you might want to check for that.

Comment: @JeppeStigNielsen How about `((BigInteger)1 << i)` to make it unlimited(!) ?

Comment: @L.B Yeah, that is great.

Answer (score 3):

Like this:

```
string binaryString = "111";
var integerValue = Convert.ToInt64(binaryString,2);
```

`integerValue` will be 7 now.

**Update, thanks to the comments:**

If you want to store each value then you need to go through the string step by step in a for loop and bit-shift (`<< operator`) to get to your desired outcome.

```
[Test]
public void BinaryStringToValues()
{
    const string binaryString = "111";
    var values = new List<int>();
    for (var i = 0; i < binaryString.Length; i++)
    {
        if (binaryString[binaryString.Length - i - 1] == '0')
        {
            continue;
        }
        values.Add(1 << i);
    }

    Assert.AreEqual(1, values[0]);
    Assert.AreEqual(2, values[1]);
    Assert.AreEqual(4, values[2]);
}
```

The test will pass.

Comment: While this answers converting from binary .. I don't know how it relates to "how do I get each integer digit (i.e. 1, 2 ,4)".. or what that even means.

Comment: Why do I have the feeling I am doing somebodies homework? :)

Comment: Probably because only a teacher would dream up an exercise as silly as this one... or you've simply been trolled.  Either way, have a +1

Comment: If you like, you can use `1 << i` instead of `(int)Math.Pow(2, i)`.

Comment: @JeppeStigNielsen :)), now I have the feeling I am back in university! Thx, looks much cooler this way! :) long time I used bit shifting

Answer (score 2):

It's not entirely clear what you want, but let's assume that from this string:

```
"1011011"
```

you want to get this array:

```
64, 16, 8, 2, 1
```

then you can use this code ([LINQPad](http://linqpad.net) program):

```
void Main()
{
    string input = "1011011";

    int[] values = input
        .Select((value, idx) => value == '1'
                ? (1 << (input.Length - idx - 1))
                : 0)
        .Where(value => value > 0)
        .ToArray();

    values.Dump();
}
```

Output:

[image: linqpad output]

This will:

- For each character that is `'1'`
- Calculate the position, from the right, where the rightmost position is position 0
- Then it will calculate `1 << x` (x is that position), which will return 1 for the rightmost position, 2 for the one left of it, 4 for the one left of 2, 8 for the next, 16, 32, 64, and so on.
- The array at this point would be `[64, 0, 16, 8, 0, 2, 1]` so we'll remove the zeroes

Comment: Thanks everyone, your feedbacks are very helpful..