# Value was either too large or too small for a UInt64

Tags: c#, string, binary

I have this code that i am trying to use to convert string of binary to decimal value. However, i am getting the following error:

> ***Value was either too large or too small for a UInt64.***

```
string a = "10100000100100110110010000010101111011011001101110111111111101000000101111001110001111100001101";
ulong value = Convert.ToUInt64(a, 2);
Console.WriteLine(value);
```

I have tried every possible solution available on the internet, but i'm still not getting the proper solution.

Comment: Your number has 95 bits (string is 95 characters long). Of course it is not going to fit into a `UInt64`.

Comment: See also: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56333862/faster-way-to-convert-large-binary-string-to-biginteger

Answer (score 2):

That string is **96** characters. So it represents 96 bits. You are trying to fit that into a `UInt64` that, not surprisingly, can hold **64** bits only.

You can use a `BigInteger` for arbitrary large numbers.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.numerics.biginteger?view=net-7.0

Comment: How to convert BigInteger (binary in my case )to decimal ?

Comment: @HarrY define "to decimal" in that sentence. What specific type are you trying to convert it to? What value do you expect? A decimal string should be fine via ToString(), however `double` and `decimal` lack the fidelity to correctly store this number - they just don't have enough bits. There is not currently a `Float128` in the main system libraries, although some seem to exist in 3rd party libs

Comment: @HarrY note that there is now an `Int128` type which would be a lot more efficient than `BigInteger`

Comment: @MarcGravell By `decimal` i mean, i want to convert this binary to a number. For Ex: Binary: 11 is 3 in decimal.

Comment: @HarrY then: `ToString()` should work, no? (on either `BigInteger` or `Int128`)

Comment: @MarcGravell No Marc, `ToString()` did not work.

Comment: @HarrY "did not work" how? What did it output? Did you try `ToString("D")`? See also: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.numerics.biginteger.tostring?view=net-7.0#system-numerics-biginteger-tostring(system-string)