# Assistance in Validating Binary

Tags: c#, validation, binary

Need help, cant figure out how to validate this as binary. Any help appreciated I know I am a noob.

Tried this... didn't work so well

```
 // } while (binaryStringIsValid(binaryStr) == false);
//static bool binaryStringIsValid(string binaryStr)
//{
//    bool valid = false;
//    foreach (char ch in binaryStr)
//    {
//        if (ch != '0' && ch != '1')
//        {
//            Console.WriteLine("String Is Invalid");
//        }
//    }valid = binaryStr.Length < 9;
//    return valid;
//}


{

    int digits = 0;
    string binaryStr = "";
    int sum = 0;
    int remainder;
    int po2 = 0;

    Console.WriteLine("Enter a valid binary string: ");
    digits = Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine());


    while (digits > 0)
    {
        remainder = digits % 10;
        sum = sum + remainder * Convert.ToInt32(Math.Pow(2, po2));
        po2 = po2 + 1;
        digits = digits / 10;
    }
    Console.WriteLine("Your binary string is equal to the decimal 
    number: " + sum);
    Console.ReadKey();

}
```

I need to make sure it has only 0's and 1's and is <9 characters long.

Comment: Check [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1271571/1997232). It's about how to validate and to parse, but without length check.

Comment: Um, `if (remainder > 1) throw ...`. -- You could also check the input string before converting to int.

Comment: `bool valid = binaryStr.Length < 9 && binaryStr.All(ch => ch == '0' || ch == '1');`

Comment: do
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Enter a valid binary string: ");
                binaryStr = Console.ReadLine();
            } while (binaryStrIsValid(binaryStr) == true);
            Console.WriteLine("A valid String");

Comment: It just doesn't catch the non binary entries. I feel like such an idiot lol. Thanks for the quick responses.

Answer (score 0):

Check this code

```
public bool IsBinary(string input) => new Regex("^[01]{1,9}$").IsMatch(input);
```